# window phone dynamic binding data

Tags: windows-phone-7, binding

I'm new winphone. I have a issue with binding data.

I have a class weather with 2 properties `Temp_C`, and `Temp_F`. I want to bind temperature to a textblock.

I also have a switch to choose `C` and `F`.

How can I do to when I switch to C => text block binding `Temp_C` when I switch to F => text block binding `Temp_F`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution could be to just have two text block and just toggle there visibility:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Temp_C}" Visibility="{Binding Checked,ElementName=temperatureTogled,Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Temp_F}" Visibility="{Binding Checked,ElementName=temperatureTogled,Converter={StaticResource boolToNotVisibilityConverter}}"/>

    <toolkit:ToggleSwitch  x:Name="temperatureTogled" .. />
```

Or otherwise another solution is just to add a Temp property and a IsCelsus property in your viewModel, do the switch between the two value inside your Temp property and bind the Temp property:

```
public class CurrentCondition : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool isC;

    public bool IsC
    {
        get { return isC; }
        set
        {
            if (isC != value)
            {
                isC = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("IsC");
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("TempShow");
            }
        }
    }

    private string temp_C;

    public string Temp_C
    {
        get { return temp_C; }
        set
        {
            if (temp_C != value)
            {
                temp_C = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Temp_C");
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("TempShow");
            }
        }
    }

    private string temp_F;

    public string Temp_F
    {
        get { return temp_F; }
        set
        {
            if (temp_F != value)
            {
                temp_F = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Temp_F");
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("TempShow");
            }
        }
    }

    private string tempShow;

    public string TempShow
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.isC == true)
            {
                return temp_C + "°C";
            }
            else
            {
                return temp_F + "°F";
            }
            return tempShow;
        }
    }
}


 <TextBlock Text="{Binding TempShow}"/>
<toolkit:ToggleSwitch  x:Name="temperatureTogled" Checked="{Binding IsC,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: Yes, I did the solution second.
`public class CurrentCondition : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {public string isC;
        public string temp_C { get; set; }
        public string temp_F { get; set; }
        string tempShow;
        public string TempShow { get{
            if (this.isC == true)
            { return temp_C + "°C";
            }else
            {
                return temp_F + "°F";
            }
            return tempShow;
        } set{
        } }`
 But I want to TempShow  auto update when I click `temperatureTogled` that don't need re-call to set  `isC`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "that don't need re-call to set isC" but I updated my response with how I would implement solution 2

Answer (score 0):

Xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraExtraLarge}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="txtTemperature" />

        <RadioButton Checked="CentTempChecked" GroupName="Temperature" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Content="C" />
        <RadioButton Checked="FarTempChecked" GroupName="Temperature" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Content="F" />
    </Grid>
```

Code Behind

```
using System.Globalization;

public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private TemperatureUnitType temperatureUnitType = TemperatureUnitType.Celsius;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindTemperature();
    }

    private void CentTempChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.temperatureUnitType = TemperatureUnitType.Celsius;

        BindTemperature();
    }

    private void FarTempChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.temperatureUnitType = TemperatureUnitType.Fahrenheit;

        BindTemperature();
    }

    private void BindTemperature()
    {
        var temperature = new Temperature();

        txtTemperature.Text = 
            this.temperatureUnitType == TemperatureUnitType.Celsius ? 
            temperature.Celsius.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) : temperature.Fahrenheit.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}

public enum TemperatureUnitType
{
    Celsius = 0,
    Fahrenheit = 1,
}

public class Temperature
{
    public double Celsius { get { return 45.3d; } }
    public double Fahrenheit { get { return 96.3d; } }
}
```

In a publication app, you should probably use the toggle control present in the WP toolkit. You should also be persisting the temperature preference in the IsolatedStorage DB.

Comment: I knew that but I want to binding from axml. some thing like that.
xaml:
`<TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraExtraLarge}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="txtTemperature" Text="{Binding Temp_C, Mode=OneWay}" />`

modal:
 `public class CurrentCondition : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string temp_C { get; set; }
        public string temp_F { get; set; }
    }`

how I can do, choose switch is C => textblock binding temp_C 
choose switch is F => textblock binding temp_F